# Can one get SSRS List area elements into the Header area?

Tags: list, reporting-services, header, repeat

I have an SSRS 2008 report that uses a list area and several subreports.  I need to have a few data items (company name, invoice number) repeat on each page that relates to that company.  The report will print pages for multiple companies, with multiple pages for each company.

I know how to get repeat headers to work.  I also know how to solve this problem if the list area query only selects 1 company.  I'm stuck, however, trying to get a list item to repeat when there are multiple companies.

I'm unaware of any method to get the outer list area's context into the report header.  Chris Hays's well read tricks http://blogs.msdn.com/ChrisHays/ seem only to work for table areas, but I've got a list area.

Any ideas?  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and came up with this solution.

1. Copied the contents of the list to the page header
2. For each field in the list, create a text box in the table detail row, name the text box to Group*FieldName*, hide the text box
3. In the header, create an "=ReportItems!Group*FieldName*" expression for each field

I had a shipment report with shipment details. When the shipment details spanned multiple pages I wanted the shipment header information repeated on each page. The solution above was effective.

Hope this helps,
Dan